# why i got this - Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again

Tags: android

[Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your app bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkcVj.png)

Comment: Did you use proper keystore alias and password?

Comment: Could it be that you uploaded the aab signed with your debug certificate?